# APIs working on emulator but now working on real device (phone). flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, android-emulator, flutter-dependencies

I am new to flutter, I am creating a flutter app where I am using different APIs(Third-party APIs).
While running the app on the emulator, It's working perfectly fine but when I generate the APK for it and install it on my phone, it's not working. 
All the design and layouts come perfectly fine but when I am about to hit login API, Nothing works.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please mention the OS versions of your Real Device and Emulator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For release build, you have to add internet permission in `AndroidManifest.xml` file that is located in `my_flutter_project/android/app/src/main/`.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
        android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
        ...
```